# Is it possible to use IE conditional comments to redirect?

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, conditional-comments

I've got a splash page which simply jams up in IE, and creating a workaround would require a tremendous amount of jQuery. Is there any way to use IE's conditional comments to skip the splash page, and redirect to the main page?

Comment: You could skip the splash page for all browsers, that would fix it.

Comment: My point is to have the splash available for browsers which support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a meta refresh inside the conditional comment:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=mainpage-url"/>
```