# how to not allow old browser user view my page?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if user's browser support query, if it don't the webpage will not show and just show a sentence say your browser can't view the page. but without Jquery , I don't know much about original javascript how to do  `#('body').html('u cant view the page');` something like that.

Comment: You mean when browsers dont support JavaScript or is disabled?

Comment: like Internet Explorer 6,7,8

Comment: You can use an [IE conditional redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189162/is-it-possible-to-use-ie-conditional-comments-to-redirect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this at the top of your HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=old.html"> 
<![endif]-->
```

And if you do this too:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://aarp.org">
<pre>
You have a browser that I do not, will not, and cannot support you using.

Please, go away now. Run along!
</pre>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> 
<html>
... Nothing to see here
</html>
<![endif]-->
```

It will redirect visitors to a page (without the above...) that will tell them how much you dislike their browser. And if the redirect takes a moment, then whatever. They get a blank page while they wait.

Note, this doesn't take into account other browsers for which you have a less than tepid appreciation for. Opera? Nope. Firefox? Nada. Maxthon? Is that still around? Safari? Uh huh. Not that one either.

So this will only work if it's IE for which you have a particular dislike. Otherwise, you would probably want to include a script include that did a redirect based on a browser sniff of some kind. Note, those are notoriously easy to defeat.

But, if you desire to hamstring those few Netscape diehards still around, check out **[Quirksmode's browser detect article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)**. It's, um, thorough.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use IE Conditional Comments

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
Sorry, Upgrade your browser!
<![endif]-->
```

#### Tutorials:

1. [QuirksMode Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exatly what you mean

but for browsers in which do not support javascript or javascript is disabled somehow
use the `<noscript>` tag to display a message

for the native javascript you can use `document.write("Hello World!")` to write any message to the documnet

```
<script >
    document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```